# mensaje comando con AREPL output

Tags: python, vscode

Alguien puede explicar por qué en AREPL me sale el siguiente mensaje?:

> AREPL requires standard_input to be hardcoded, like so: standard_input
> = 'hello world'; print(input())

Me resulta un poco molesto a la hora de hacer mis cosas en VSCode. Cómo se podría arreglar?
Thankya!